# How to disable submit till only required fields are filled up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, disabled-input

I have searched but I get info about how to disable submit button till `all fields` are completed....

I have following form where some fields are `required` and some are `optional`.

**I want to disable submit button till `required` fields are completed.**

sample code of form :

```
<form name="registration_form" id="registration_form" action="nextaction.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
Name : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
Email : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
Mobile : <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" required>
Gender : <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender" >/*optional*/
Occupation : <input type="text" id="occupation" name="occupation" >/*optional*/
City : <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required>
Avatar : <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" required>

<input type="submit" class="link-button-blue" id="register" value="PROCEED TO NEXT STEP" />
```

===========

**Edited**

what I have tried for submit disable untill all field completed as follows :

**First Thing :**

```
<input type="submit" class="link-button-blue" id="register" value="PROCEED TO NEXT STEP" disabled="disabled" />
```

**script :**

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {

     var empty = false;
      $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
     });

      if (empty) {
         $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
         $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); 
      }
   });
});        
</script>
```

Comment: what have you found as a solution for `all fields`? The solution can probably be translated to only `required` ones

Comment: `1. Select all required input elements with jquery or javascript` `2. Check to see if the required fields are filled` `3. Do the enable/disable of button depending on if all are filled or not`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#registration_form input[required]').on('input propertychange paste change', function() {

  var empty = $('#registration_form').find('input[required]').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
  });

  $('#register').prop('disabled', (empty.length));

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ot5kn5c7/

This should work.

Anytime anything changes on any required input check for the count of required fields that are not empty. Once there are 0 required empty inputs update the disabled property for the button. (0 evaluates as false)

If you didn't to disable the button and wanted to only stop the form from submitting you would attach to the submit event on the form and just prevent the default action using similar logic checking the length.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

  var empty = $(this).find('input[required]').filter(function() {
    return this.value == '';
  });

  if (empty.length) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('enter all required field!')
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent posting the form on a `button` or `input type="submit"`, you can simply use `e.preventDefault()` which would prevent from proceeding with the default behavior.If you are using `jquery` `validation` and have a `required` attribute, you can just invoke `$.validate()` to validate the form.

```
$('input:submit').click(function(e)
{
 if(!$.validate())
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/suj951ga/1/

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for your case: https://jsfiddle.net/j9r5ejho/

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 var valid = true;
 $('input[required]').each(function(i, el){
    if(valid && $(el).val()=='' ) valid = false; 
 })

return valid;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but it should work with something like this:

```
(function() {
    // whenever you type in a field
    $('form > input').keyup(function() {
        var empty = false;
        // scan all fields in this form with the attribute required
        $('form').find('input[required]').each(function() {
            // if it's empty, cancel the loop
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        // in case we have an empty required field, 
        // disable submit button
        if (empty) {
            $('input:submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to try something like this. This won't disable the submit button but if you want to stop it from submitting until all required fields are fill in. This should work.

Not sure what database your using but this is for the PDO. You can just change the connection part to mysqli.

- It won't submit to your database until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

  ```
   <?php
   // define variables and set to empty values
     $nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
     $name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
       $nameErr = "Please add a name";
    } else {
        $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white 
        space allowed";} 
      }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
      $emailErr = "Please add an email";
    } else {
       $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
       // check if email is an email format
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
      }

   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
      $cityErr = "Please add your city";
    } else {
      $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
      // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
          $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
      $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
    } else {
      $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
         // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
          $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
      }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
      $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
    } else {
      $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

      }
  }

  // Validate Form Data 
  function validateInput($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }


  if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
    {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "myDBPDO";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
        VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "Success! Form Submitted!";
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

    $conn = null;
  }

  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .error {color: #FF0000;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body> 




  <h2>PHP Form</h2>
  <p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
    <div class="error">
      <p><span>* required field</span></p>
      <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
      <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
      <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
      <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
      <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
    </div>
      <label for="name">Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
          <span class="error">*</span>
      </label>
      <label for="email">Email:
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
          <span class="error">*</span>
      </label>
      <label for="city">city:
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
          <span class="error">*</span>
      </label>
      <label for="comment">comment:
        <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
          <span class="error">*</span>
      </label>
      <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
          <span class="error">*</span>
      </label>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Use this if you want to redirect it to another page so it won't send the form again to your PDO database if they refresh it.

- It won't submit to your database and will stay on the HOME.PHP page until you complete all the required fields and will also display the required input error messages while on HOME.PHP page.
- It won't clear all the fields if you forget to fill in one of the required fields and submit.

Added a "header("Location: welcome.php");" after "$conn->exec($sql);"

**HOME.PHP**

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $cityErr = $commentErr = $genderErr = "";
$name = $email = $city = $comment = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Please add a name";
  } else {
    $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+/",$name)) {$nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";} 
    }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Please add an email";
  } else {
    $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
    // check if email is an email format
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $cityErr = "Please add your city";
  } else {
    $city = validateInput($_POST["city"]);
    // check if city only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
        $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $commentErr = "Please add your comment";
  } else {
    $comment = validateInput($_POST["comment"]);
       // check if comment only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
        $commentErr = 'Only "/", "-", "+", and numbers';  
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Please pick your gender";
  } else {
    $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);

    }
}

// Validate Form Data 
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }


if(!empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["city"]) && !empty($_POST["comment"]) && !empty($_POST["gender"]))
  {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "myDBPDO";

  try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      // set the PDO error mode to exception
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, email, city, comment, gender)
      VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$comment', '$gender')";
      // use exec() because no results are returned
      $conn->exec($sql);
      header("Location: welcome.php");
      }
  catch(PDOException $e)
      {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
      }

  $conn = null;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 




<h2>PHP Form</h2>
<p>Doesn't submit until the required fields you want are filled</p>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
  <div class="error">
    <p><span>* required field</span></p>
    <div><?php echo $nameErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $emailErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $cityErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $commentErr;?></div>
    <div><?php echo $genderErr;?></div>              
  </div>
    <label for="name">Name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="email">Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="city">city:
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $city;?>">
       <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="comment">comment:
      <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="<?php echo $comment;?>">
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
    <label for="gender">Gender:<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
        <span class="error">*</span>
    </label>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WELCOME.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Success! Form Submitted!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```